# Changing field of view for a 360 VR video in Premiere - adjusting default zoom level

Tags: premiere, 360video, zoom, vr

I have a 360 video, and when I view it with a video player, I find the field of view too narrow. I would like to widen the field of view so that the video is a little more "zoomed out". I've spent a good chunk of time on this, but haven't been able to figure out a way to achieve this in Premiere Pro.